# {Malicious File makes all my wordpress websites corrupted} Error : 503 Service Unavailable The server is temporarily busy, try again later

Tags: wordpress, security

[**Screenshot:** Error : 503 Service Unavailable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIEcU.png)

all my websites are showing this error page also the cpu usage bumps up by 100% instantly at 3:30 pm and the hosting support also not able to help me

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have that problem too, zip all plugins and download in your pc via filemanager and then try one by one to activate to see the corrupted plugin